The "Picker" in the "Collection view" does not pre-select any values in MAUI while the binding is working on the label
I'm trying to make the liaison between 2 observable collections : Milestones, Categories
On the model "Milestone", I've got a property "SelectedCategory"
public Category SelectedCategory
{
    get => selectedCategory;
    set
    {
        if (selectedCategory != value)
        {
            selectedCategory = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedCategory));
        }
    }
}

And I select it on the code-behind for each milestone :
foreach (var m in Milestones)
{
    m.SelectedCategory = Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.IdCategory == m.IdCategory);
}

However, the problem is that when I try to pre-select this category in my selector, nothing has been pre-selected.
After checking all the code behind, I'm pretty sure the problem comes from the XAML :
<CollectionView Grid.Row="1" Margin="25,10,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Milestones}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

                <Picker Grid.Column="2"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BindingContext.Categories, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ModifyProjectPage}}}"
                ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding CategoryName}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory, Mode=TwoWay}" />   

        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>

By the way, the binding is working, I can see all category names and when I'm trying to do it with a label everything is working perfectly. And there is no error in the console
<Label Text="{Binding SelectedCategory.CategoryName}" />
Binding doesn't work without Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ModifyProjectPage}}} :
<Picker Grid.Column="2"
ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding CategoryName}"
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory, Mode=TwoWay}" /> 


The code of binding looks good. The Picker control is placed in the DataTemplate and the ItemsSource Property binds to Categories in ViewModel. So you may use Relative Bindings for ItemsSource of Picker.
Another reason that I believe it's not a binding issue is that if I set a small delay, the PreSelected Picker Item will be displayed successfully.
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    await Task.Delay(50);

    foreach (var m in viewModel.Milestones)
    {
        m.SelectedCategory = viewModel.Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.IdCategory == m.IdCategory);         
    }
}

However it's not a good solution. I can also reproduce this issue and you may consider raising an issue on Github.

It works, but as you said it's not a good solution, I found other similar problems on maui's github. Unfortunately, the problem was already mentioned a year ago and still hasn't been fixed.

Yeah it‘s just a workaround. Sometimes using delay might cause slightly laggy. And how much delay to set also depends on the performance of different devices.  For known MAUI issue, it's recommended you track the issue, communicate with our engineers directly to let them know your concerns and needs.

I've met a similar issue, I think it's related to how Picker is implemented, somehow the code doesn't receive your SelectedItem as member of the ObservableCollection, and just can't find it in the Collection. The workaround I usually did was not to set SelectedItem, but set SelectedIndex instead.
Have a look to this question, I was pretty new to Maui at this time but I think it could help you.

Using SelectedIndex doesn't work either.
I've also tried setting SelectedIndex="1" and no items are selected either.
